# SonataUserBundle error while getting users list

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I have installed a SonataAdminBundle, a SonataUserBundle, FOSUserBundle and my own bundle, that extends FOSUserBundle.

mysite/admin/dashboard looks OK, but when I try to get a users list (mysite/admin/sonata/user/user/list) I get this error:

> Class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User does not exist

Why? What I have to do?

**UPD:**

Okay, now I figured out that problem, but now I have another one.

> No route found for "GET /admin/sonata/user/user/list"

Why this rout does not exist? Where these routes should be placed and why there are none of them in basic SonataUserBundle installation?

Comment: Have you created a User class that extends `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User`? See step 3 in the documentation of FOSUserBundle: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: Yes, I wrote: "FOSUserBundle and my own bundle, that extends FOSUserBundle."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow all steps in the [installation chapter](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html) of the SonataUserBundle? Maybe you missed step 2.3.2 which adds the user admin routes.

Comment: Yes, I missed. Because I didn't find this guide on userbundle page at all. So I had been trying to install it manually, without any docs... Can you say where did you find this link?

Comment: The documentation of the Sonata project bundles can be found on http://sonata-project.org/bundles/.

Comment: Clear. But what if my FOSUserBundle is extended by my own User Entiry, form type and handler? It doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I have such a bad reputation, therefore I cannot add comments yet. In reply to the comment of Hast:

> Clear. But what if my FOSUserBundle is extended by my own User Entiry,
>   form type and handler? It doesn't work in this case

Thanks to [Extending Sonata User Bundle and adding new fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621993/extending-sonata-user-bundle-and-adding-new-fields)

Add this to your config:

```
sonata_user:
    class:
        user: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User
        group: Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Group
```