# Extending SonataAdmin User with ManyToMany field

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am currently trying to extend the SonataUserBundle's User to add a new ManyToMany relationship with a existing Entity.

I extended the User based on the answer found here - [Extending Sonata User Bundle and adding new fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621993/extending-sonata-user-bundle-and-adding-new-fields/15625000#15625000)

User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Pledge", inversedBy="pledgedUsers")
 **/
private $pledgedOn;

// (...) generated getters and setters here
```

Pledge.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="pledgedOn")
 **/
private $pledgedUsers;

// (...) generated getters and setters here
```

The first thing I noticed when I sync the schema, is that it creates 2 pivot tables, instead of just one: `pledge_user` and `user_pledge`. I tried adding a `@ORM\JoinTable` in, but that's just changing the name of one. When I add the same `@ORM\JoinTable` to both, I get the 'table already exists' error.

When I try to access the user list in admin, I am getting a big sql error

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT count(DISTINCT u0_.id) AS sclr0 FROM User u0_ LEFT JOIN fos_user_user_group f2_ ON u0_.id = f2_.user_id LEFT JOIN fos_user_group f1_ ON f1_.id = f2_.group_id':

SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column u0_.id does not exist
```

I am sure this is something simple, but I am smacking my head finding the source of this problem. What did I miss?

Full User.php: http://pastebin.com/TXunsgm1

Full Pledge.php: http://pastebin.com/Mta6aiVm

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was a derpy error. I had

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="pledgedOn")
```

and

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Pledge", inversedBy="pledgedUsers")
```

One of them had to be `mappedBy` instead of `inversedBy` . Changing the second one to

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Pledge", mappedBy="pledgedUsers")
```

fixed the problem.