# How to remove and add column on user table in symfony, sonata adminBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

In symfony sonata admin bundle, whether we can remove or add columns in the fos user table, like remove social column and add image profile column.

thanks.

Comment: I suggest to add some more info about what have you done so far, unless you don't want angry stack overflow users to downvote you a lot.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621993/extending-sonata-user-bundle-and-adding-new-fields