# sonata add more field in user bundle admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

i'm a noob of sonata, i'm loooking for extends user field list of admin bundle, i try various solution founded but i can't resolve my problem.

i already extends userAdmin class:

```
        contexts: [admin]
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User


    group:
        group_class:   Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager                    # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.group_manager for mongodb)

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager                      # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager for mongodb)

sonata_user:
  admin:
    user:
      class:      Ap\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
    group:
      class:      Ap\UserBundle\Admin\Model\GroupAdmin
```

but i imagine that i must extends BaseUser entity, is right?

ps. i use symfony 2.8 version

thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621993/extending-sonata-user-bundle-and-adding-new-fields

Comment: i already tried this way, but i get a correct fos_user, but i can't logged in sonata cms with user created in fos_user